# How to get standard styleClass attribute in custom component which extends UIOutput

Tags: jsf-2, attributes, custom-component

I'm using below custom component to display some kind of guidance in my page. I was asked to pass `text` and `styleClass` attributes to this component. But unfortunately `styleClass` attribute alone is NOT getting applied when this component gets rendered in the page. And thus I've hard coded with in my tag component. And this time style is getting applied properly. Not sure why. Can  any one sugegst?

I can see `styleClass` attribute from css is getting passed to tag component properly. As I mentioned above component is getting rendered with out the passed style class applied.

If I hard code my style as below then it is working.

```
writer.writeAttribute("style", "background-color: #F1F5F2;font-size: 80%;left: 52em;position: absolute;text-align: left;width: 13.25em;z-index: 5;", null);
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

The custom component is used as follows

```
<mytags:guidanceBox text="#{FindPersonProps.MY_GUIDANCE_TEXT}" styleClass="guidance_css" />
```

The source code is below:

```
@FacesComponent(value="tags.guidanceBox")
public class GuidanceTag extends UIOutput {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "javax.faces.NamingContainer";
    }

    public GuidanceTag() {
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        String guidanceText=(String) getAttributes().get("text");
        //String styleClass=(String) getAttributes().get("styleClass");
        //System.err.println("Text ["+guidanceText+"] Style ["+styleClass+"]");

        ResponseWriter writer=context.getResponseWriter();
        String clientId=getClientId(context);
        writer.startElement("p", this);
        writer.writeAttribute("style", "background-color: #F1F5F2;font-size: 80%;left: 52em;position: absolute;text-align: left;width: 13.25em;z-index: 5;", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, "clientId");

        writer.startElement("b", null);
        writer.writeText("Guidance:", null);
        writer.endElement("b");

        writer.startElement("br", null);
        writer.endElement("br");

        writer.writeText(guidanceText, null);

        writer.endElement("p");

    }
```

Comment: The family choice is quite strange. So to exclude the one and other; is this component been used by `<cc:interface componentType>` or so?

Comment: I wasn't very sure about the family choice. I just gave it by referring some other example. does it make any sincere difference during component rendering? And it is not used by a composite component.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement TagHandler, that is passing the attributes to implementation of your component itself. Something like this:

```
public class GuidanceTagHandler extends ComponentHandler {

    public GuidanceTagHandler(ComponentConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComponentCreated(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent c, UIComponent parent) {
        super.onComponentCreated(ctx, c, parent);

        TagAttribute styleClassAttribute = getRequiredAttribute("styleClass");
        c.getAttributes().put("styleClass", styleClassAttribute);
    }
}
```

in taglib.xml you should have a signature of your component:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>guidanceTag</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>guidance</component-type>
        <handler-class>yourpackages.GuidanceTagHandler</handler-class>
    </component>
</tag>
```

and finally in faces.config (it will bind on the `component-type` attribute

```
<component>
    <component-type>guidance</component-type>
    <component-class>yourpackages.GuidanceTag</component-class>
</component>
```

I hope this answer will help you a bit, since I was once having the same problem. So this is the solution I came up with.

Comment: @Premma - thanks for ur time. will try this tomorrow and let you know the update.

Comment: @BalusC - I like most of ur answers. what made u to say 'not required'?

Comment: @Balus maybe it is not required, but it is, that helped me to solve similar problem. Maybe you can solve the problem using annotations, but if we have the whole project in XML configuration, I'll stick with that.